# Camera picture saving incorrectly on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera

I have application that captures image and save it with overlaying image. Image which places above the captured picture is like a border with transparent part in center. The problem is that on some devices picture is broken and looks like this
[image]

So brown border is ok but captured image is not ok. Specifically it reproduces on HTC sense 3.6 (Android 4.0.3)
At first I'm capture image and create bitmap with border. Than I'm save it on sdcard and show it in the next activity. Here my code:

```
private class CameraPictureCallback implements Camera.PictureCallback {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = PictureStorage.getOutputMediaFile(PictureStorage.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Logger.getInstance().log("Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }

        if (data != null) {

            Bitmap border = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.photo_frame);

            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = 4;
            Bitmap origin_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(mRotation);

            //Border is 640x640px
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(origin_bitmap, border.getWidth(), border.getHeight(), false);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(border.getWidth(), border.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas s = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
            s.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
            s.drawBitmap(border, 0f, 0f, null);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                if (resultBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)) {
                    fos.close();
                }
                resultBitmap.recycle();
                bitmap.recycle();
                border.recycle();
                origin_bitmap.recycle();

                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), PictureConfirmActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("filename", pictureFile.getPath());
                getContext().startActivity(i);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Logger.getInstance().log(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getInstance().log(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't reproduce on any my device, but problem is very actual and i need resolve it. I can imagine that it can be here, `resultBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)`, but it's just a thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with setting correct size of preview. I chose first available screen size wich cause such unpredictable result. So right solution is to find appropriate size of preview

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    //some code before...
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size previewSize = getBestPreviewSize(w, h, parameters);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
}

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            }
            else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (result == null) {
        result = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().get(0);
    }

    return result;
}
```